# Using bootstrap phone input in a Django Form

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I am trying to incorporate phone input from Bootstrap, as shown here: http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/

I want to use it in my Django form, but it isn't working for some reason. Here is my relevant code:

forms.py

```
class InstructorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    home_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone'}), max_length=128, label="Home Phone")
    work_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone'}), max_length=128, label="Work Phone")
    cell_phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone'}), max_length=128, label="Cell Phone")
    fax = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control bfh-phone'}), max_length=128, required=False, label="Fax")
```

add_new_instructor.html

```
<form id="instructor_form" method="post" action="/schedule/add_new_instructor/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="col-gl-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>{{ field.errors }}</strong>
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    <br>
                    {{ field }}
                    <script></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Add New Instructor</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Reset</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_javascript %}
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#id_home_phone').attr("data-format", "+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd");
                $('#id_work_phone').attr("data-format", "+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd");
                $('#id_cell_phone').attr("data-format", "+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd");
                $('#id_fax').attr("data-format", "+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd");
            }
        );

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The form itself is showing, but for some reason, the phone number fields do not work the way they're supposed to in the link and instead treating like it's not even there. There's not even an error showing, and I'm positive that I have all the proper links and plugins.

Also, if someone could, could someone tell me how to incorporate an optional extension in the work phone field? Thanks.

Edit: Actually, I've noticed something weird when looking at my model:

models.py

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[validate_email])
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    state = USStateField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, default="NJ")
    zipcode = USZipCodeField(blank=True)
    #points of interest
    home_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    work_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #end points of interest
    course = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=INSTRUCTOR_STATUS_CHOICES)
    description = models.TextField()
```

When I tried migrating this model, the fields with phone numbers required a default and I had to type in null=True, even though they're CharFields and none of the other CharFields have this problem. Perhaps this has something to do with why it's not working?

Comment: Could you, please, right-click on the rendered page and select "View page source". Then, copy-paste this (the entire HTML) into your question, in order to have a better look?

Comment: The source is incredibly long since there is a bunch of unrelated stuff that I did not mention.

Comment: Why do you set `data-format` with jQuery? Move those to the Django form widget attrs.

Comment: If it's long then just copy-paste only the relevant parts. The head section and the form one.